# A tag for the Legrand Orange template

Tags: discussion

I thought about requesting a tag for the Legrand Orange template that is very popular in this community. But is this possible? Is this a kind of advertising or would it not?

**EDIT**

As this template seems not to be so popular, let's imagine that I find another one that is really popular, requesting a TAG for the given template would be feasible?

Comment: A quick search yields about 30 questions for this tag: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Legrand+Orange%22+%09is%3Aquestion

Comment: I have to say I've never heard of it ....

Comment: What would be a good average?

Comment: Thinking better, my question was really different.

Comment: It is possible to create new tags, users do it all the time, for example `hyperef`, or `bbok` or basically any typo imaginable. Tags that seem reasonable stay while ther get deleted over time (by not being used).

Comment: Though we have a few tags for templates, for example `classicthesis`,  cleanthesis` (what about `moderncv` or `awesome-cv`) i consider all of them *bleep*. As there is an infinite amount of templates, and not even a clear (agreed) definition of template, i guess the tag `template` is sufficient.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Don't forget the `templates-are-waste-of-time` tag ;-)

Comment: Please don't start yet another edit rush. Templates are not worth it.